# How Synchronized and Concurrent Collections are thread-safe but their content not

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, parallel-processing, thread-safety

From this [source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety#concurrent-collections) one can read:

> It's worth mentioning that synchronized and concurrent collections
> only make the collection itself thread-safe and not the contents.

I thought if `Collection` is thread-safe then its content will implicitly be thread-safe.

I mean if two threads cannot access my `Collection` object then the object which my `Collection` object is holding will implicitly become thread-safe.

I missing the point, could someone please explain me with an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

The objects stored in a thread-safe collection can be leaked outside and used in a non-thread-safe manner.

**Detailed Answer:**

> I thought if Collection is thread-safe then its content will
> implicitly be thread-safe, I mean if two threads cannot access my
> Collection object then the object which my Collection object is
> holding will implicitly become thread-safe.
>
> I know sure I missing the point, **could someone please explain me with
> an example.**

Consider the following code that uses two threads to add to the same **non-thread-safe list** the elements from `0 to 10`. In the end, the *main* thread sums all the elements of that list. The final result should be same as `0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + ... 9 + 9 = 90.` However, if you execute the code a couple of times you get different values, and sometimes even the following `NPE`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$1ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:553)
    at Z.CollectionThreadSafe.main(CollectionThreadSafe.java:26)
```

All this is the result of the race-condition during the call of the method `add`.

```
private static void addToList(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        list.add(i);
}

public static void main(String[] arg) throws InterruptedException {
    final int TOTAL_THREADS = 2;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TOTAL_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_THREADS; i++) {
        pool.submit(() -> addToList(list));
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(list.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum));
}
```

Let us fix the race-condition by using a thread-Safe `List` by calling [Collections.synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)). So let us adapt the previous code to:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

You can run it as many times as you want; the final result is always the same *i.e.,* `90`. That much we knew already. Let us showcase the:

> It's worth mentioning that synchronized and concurrent collections
> only make the collection itself thread-safe and not the contents.

You just need to adapt the previous code from:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

to:

```
final List<List<Integer>> LIST_THREAD_SAFE = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
LIST_THREAD_SAFE.add(new ArrayList<>());
List<Integer> list = LIST_THREAD_SAFE.get(0);
...
```

and *voilá!* you have exactly the same situation as the first example that we have showcased (*i.e.,* race-condition). Even though the list `LIST_THREAD_SAFE` is thread-safe its content is not. Hence,

> synchronized and concurrent collections **only** make the collection
> itself thread-safe **and not the contents.**

Answer (score 2):

If the collection is thread safe two thread can still access the collection simultaneously. They also could do modification simultaneously if this does not influence the the coherence of the collection. It is guaranteed only that all operation are consistent possibly with the minimum amount of locks.
This has no relation with the object in the collection: one thread can get a reference of an object from the collection and keep for a certain amount of time and so other threads can get the same reference from the collection (in the same time o later) and access the object in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The access to the elements is thread-safe but not the usage of them. Two threads get access to the same element (one after the other) and both are calling methods on the element after that. The collection would not even know.